# Trying to remove duplicates from list not working

Tags: javascript

I want to print the usernames of the email addresses supplied in a `<textarea>`, but without the duplicates.

```
<textarea id="emailTextarea" rows ="10" cols="25" >
sara@yahoo.com
adam@yahoo.com
todd@yahoo.com
henry@yahoo.com
wright@yahoo.com
sara@yahoo.com
adam@yahoo.com
todd@yahoo.com
</textarea>

<body onload="emailSort()">

<script>
//email sort function

function emailSort(){

    //get data from the textarea

    var emailList = document.getElementById("emailTextarea").value;

    //put into array
    var emailListArray = emailList.split("\n");

    //remove the extension and duplicates

    var usernamesArray = emailListArray.map(function(val, index, arr) {
            var username = val.slice(0, val.indexOf('yahoo.com'));
        if(!val[username]) val[username] = true;
        return emailUsers;

    });

    //sort the list

    var sortedUsernames = usernamesArray.sort();

    //print out the list

    document.write(sortedUsernames.join('</br>'));
}
```

Comment: @MJB, you will get better, more helpful answers if you cut down your question to cover only the problem you're having. For example, you could leave out all the html, and just show a javascript array of email addresses (or usernames) that you want to remove duplicates from.

Answer (score 2):

In case you can use [lo-dash](https://lodash.com/docs), try this:

```
var emails = _.compact(document.getElementById('emailTextarea').value.split("\n"));

console.log('Sorted unique emails', _.uniq(emails).sort());
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/j6cnzpdv/

---

Without Lodash:

```
var sortedUniqueEmails = document.getElementById('emailTextarea').value
    // Build array of emails
    .split("\n")

    // Sort
    .sort()

    // Remove invalid/falsy entries (ie. blank lines)
    .filter(function(line) {
        return line.indexOf('@') > -1; // Assuming this is enough to validate an email
    })

    // Remove duplicates
    .reduce(function(result, email) {
      if (result.indexOf(email) < 0) result.push(email);

      return result;
    }, []);

console.log('Sorted unique emails', sortedUniqueEmails);
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/xa2Ltxth/

Comment: I am not able to use lo-dash.

Comment: @MJB, I edited the answer and added a non-Lodash version - good luck!

Answer (score 0):

This is my version of Claudio's solution, but without lo-dash and including removal of "@yahoo.com":

```
var uniques = new Set();
emails.split("\n").sort().forEach(function(i){
                uniques.add(i);
});
var uniquesTrimmed = [];
uniques.forEach(function(val){uniquesTrimmed.push(val.slice(0, val.indexOf('@yahoo.com')))});
```

Try it here: http://jsfiddle.net/j6cnzpdv/1/

Comment: Thank you Andrea Dusza. I am using Tryit Editor v2.5. For some reason, I am not able to use _.uniq(_.compact(emails.split("\n"))).sort();.  Is there another way to remove the duplicates?

Answer (score 0):

Try this example:

```js
function emailSort() {
  var emails = document.getElementById("emailTextarea").value.split("\n");
  var users = [],  l = emails.length, id;
  while (l--)
    if ((id = emails[l].match(/\w+@/)) && (-1 === users.indexOf(id[0])))
      users.push(id[0]);
  alert(users.sort().join(", "));
}
```

```html
<body onload="emailSort()">
  <textarea id="emailTextarea" rows ="10" cols="25" >
  sara@yahoo.com
  adam@yahoo.com
  todd@yahoo.com
  henry@yahoo.com
  wright@yahoo.com
  sara@yahoo.com
  adam@yahoo.com
  todd@yahoo.com
  </textarea>
</body>
```

Comment: How would I modify the above code to keep the @, and removing the yahoo.com, so the output would be adam@, henry@, etc?

Comment: @MJB, kindly find my updates